# JavaScript: I cannot use CSS with JS

Tags: javascript, css

How do I can use CSS with JS?

My code is: (please, look at the picture that I have attached).

How do I can write a ID in document.write?[image]

Comment: Problem is the JS results in a *syntax error*. The above [invalid] expression supplied to `write` is tokenized as: `"<h1 id="`, `text`, `">Your name is "`, `+`, `userName`. Hmm :) In any case, please post *text*, not images and include the *actual* error message.

Comment: You should never post code as an image. Stackoverflow has support for markdown and syntax hilighting. Alternatively, you can post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code. Also, please explain what error you're encountering, including details from the console. Last, try not to assume the problem if you don't know what it is "i.e., "cannot use css with js" when the real problem is "js syntax error."

Comment: Apart from the other issues, the additional semicolon after your color property is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `document.write('<h1 id="text">Your name is '+userName);` Note the different of quotation marks. Currently you are closing your JS string with the quotation marks you use in the id attribute.

Comment: Note sure why this was downvoted ..

Comment: @user2246674 Same here. It looks like someone has downvoted every answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotations for the class instead of a second set of double quotes. Alternatively you can backslash double quotes as well.

Comment: While this is correct, a little bit of code (e.g. examples) can make it an even better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
document.write("<h1 id="text">Your name is " +username);
```

to this:

```
document.write('<h1 id="text">Your name is ' +username);`
```

Alternatively, you could escape the quotes like this:

```
document.write("<h1 id=\"text\">Your name is " +username);
```

You're confusing the JavaScript parser, it thinks you're closing the string when you are opening the attribute.

Comment: Downvoters: please comment to explain your downvotes. It helps everyone learn.

Comment: @showdev I'm guessing it's because your code was wrong. I added in the missing `<` characters.

Comment: @xdumaine Ah, I see that now. I hated having to type from the image.

Comment: @xdumaine It's not my code. But thanks for editing/commenting!

Comment: @showdev oops! Wasn't paying attention to commenter versus answerer.

Comment: :D 

Sorry for that I have attached exactly image.